# How to use optional fields in addform?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, insert

I have a form here: http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/evenementform

as you can see I have a button with a `+` to add a second date to the event. All is working when I fill in everything (so both date field) when I leave the optional one blank I'm getting an error because it's empty.

I tried something to use those optional fields only if they're filled in, but I could not figure out how.

I think I have to use a foreach loop.

My code to insert the fields into the database:

```
public function addevenement($image_data = array())
{
    $data = array(
        'titel' => $this->input->post('titel'),
        'waar' => $this->input->post('waar'),
        'entree' => $this->input->post('entree'),
        'organisatie' => $this->input->post('organisatie'),
        'omschrijving' => $this->input->post('omschrijving'),
        'www' => $this->input->post('www'),
        'tel' => $this->input->post('tel'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'afbeelding' => $image_data['file_name']
    );          
    $this->db->insert('agenda', $data);

    $id = $this->db->insert_id();

        $data2 = array(
            'idagenda' => $id,
            'datum' => $this->input->post('datum'),
            'van' => $this->input->post('van'),
            'tot' => $this->input->post('tot')
        );


    $this->db->join('agenda', 'agendadatum.idagenda = agenda.idagenda');
    $this->db->where('agendadatum.idagenda', $id);
    $post = $this->input->post();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($post['datum']); $i++) {
       $this->db->insert('agendadatum', array('idagenda' => $id, 'datum' => $post['datum'][$i], 'van' => $post['van'][$i], 'tot' => $post['tot'][$i]));
    }; 
    redirect('agenda');
}
```

How can I make the second date field optional so it skips them when they're empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($post['datum']); $i++) {
    if( $post['datum'][$i] != "" ){
        $this->db->insert('agendadatum', array('idagenda' => $id, 'datum' => $post['datum'][$i], 'van' => $post['van'][$i], 'tot' => $post['tot'][$i]));    
    }

};
```

Comment: Still not working. I'm getting this error: `Error Number: 1292

Incorrect date value: '' for column 'datum' at row 1

INSERT INTO `agendadatum` (`idagenda`, `datum`, `van`, `tot`) VALUES (26, '', '', '')`

Comment: Yeah that worked, why couldn't I come with this myself lol. Thanks

Comment: Happie to help :D @KeesSonnema